# Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string - when querying the database

Tags: sql-server

The following code:

```
DECLARE @dateAsString AS nvarchar
SET @dateAsString = '2020-04-28T12:51:33.587Z'
DECLARE @dateObject as DATETIME
SET @dateObject = CAST(@dateAsString as DATETIME)

SELECT DATEDIFF(DAY, @dateObject, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
```

I get this error:

> Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 6
> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string

How can I ensure that the date stored in the database does not give me this error?

`Convert` and `Cast` didn't do the trick... please help!

Comment: Try `SELECT @dateAsString` and see if that confirms to your expectations (it won't). Always declare the length of a (n)varchar!

Comment: It is FAR better to store datetime values in a datetime or datetime2 column rather than varchar/nvarchar. At some point someone will manage to store a value that cannot be converted - what should happen then?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason for the error is that you need to define the size of the `@dateAsString` nvarchar variable. When the size is not specified the default length is `1` and the actual value of the `@dateAsString` variable is `2`.

Also, as an option, you may use `CONVERT()` with an appropriate date and time style:

```
DECLARE @dateAsString AS nvarchar(24)
SET @dateAsString = N'2020-04-28T12:51:33.587Z'
DECLARE @dateObject as DATETIME

--SET @dateObject = CAST(@dateAsString as DATETIME)
SET @dateObject = CONVERT(datetime, @dateAsString, 127)

SELECT DATEDIFF(DAY, @dateObject, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is ok, only your nvarchar was to small to hold you data

> ```
> DECLARE @dateAsString AS nvarchar(28)
> SET @dateAsString = '2020-04-28T12:51:33.587Z'
> DECLARE @dateObject as DATETIME
> SET @dateObject = CAST(@dateAsString as DATETIME )
>
> SELECT DATEDIFF(DAY, @dateObject, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
> ```

> ```
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> | (No column name) |
> | ---------------: |
> |              174 |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=177ac228ed4b742ce4daa400a4ae9b3a)*